# jquery ajax not passing data to php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass javascript Date object to php, but when i **dump** $_POST it returns empty array or string. I am doing this in same file, so in 
file.php are php code and javascript code. Also javascript shows that everything is correct because it alert in success function.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST); //returns empty array
var_dump($_POST['zone']); //returns null
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var date = new Date();
  $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data: {zone : date},
      success: function(data){
         alert("test"); //this runs normally
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(error);
      }     
  });   
</script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101008/discussion-on-question-by-user1814358-jquery-ajax-not-passing-data-to-php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code I tested on phpfiddle.org:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['zone'])){
    // Only runs when there is a Post for 'zone'
    //var_dump($_POST);
    echo $_POST['zone'];
} else{
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var date = new Date();
            function postZone(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    data: {zone : date},
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        //alert("test"); //this runs normally
                        $("#zone").html(data.substring(data.indexOf("(")) + " is client TimeZone.");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                        console.log(xhr.statusText);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(error);
                    }     
                });   
            }
            postZone();
        </script>
        Running Post.
        <div id='zone'></div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here is what I saw in the Post results:

```
array(1) {
  ["zone"]=>
  string(57) "Mon Jan 18 2016 09:44:17 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
}
string(57) "Mon Jan 18 2016 09:44:17 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
```

Adding the `if` statement helps to not confuse the results. Not sure how you'll do this if you're including this code. As I said in my comment, you;re not passing the Date object in your Post, so you should pass the specifics of what you need to PHP.

**Edit**

Updated code. You can now see the `data` in console and the results show are:

```
Running Post.
(Pacific Standard Time) is client TimeZone.
```

This of course will be different for each client.

Comment: Not works :/ Even i tried in new file. It alert test, but not dump it from php...

Comment: The dump is sent back to your Ajax, and since you don't do anything with the `data`, you're not seeing it. What do you want done with the data that is returned?

Comment: No errors. Success function runned because it alert test.

Comment: Made a minor update to my code. No more alert, but you can see the manipulated data now.

Comment: FINNALY WORKS ! If you ever come to Serbia, mail me on srdjan.nezic@yahoo.com you have beer from me ! :D Thank you.

Comment: Will do! No idea when that might be, since I do not get out of the US too often. I will add it to places to visit.